# Does every Lie group have at most countably many connectected components?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, lie-groups, connectedness, second-countable

Some proofs in a lecture I took were motivated by this statement that "some people don't assume second countability when they define a topological manifold, but for Lie groups we get this property for free". They then proved the statement "if a Lie group G has at most countably many connected components then G is second countable" alongside some other related topological results. I see how if we assume second countability in our definition of a topological manifold that we must have at most countably many connected components. So I see the if and only if statement, but this isn't the same thing as saying every Lie group is second countable.

So my question is if we don't include second countability in our definition of a topological manifold can we show every Lie group has at most countably many connected components? If not is there an example of a Lie group that this definition admits that is excluded when we assume topological manifolds are second countable?

Comment: The more interesting implication is that if a Lie group is connected (assuming only locally Euclidean and Hausdorff), then it is 2nd countable. Or, every Lie group is paracompact.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take $\Bbb R\times\Bbb R$, where the first $\Bbb R$ has its usual structure as a differentiable manifold, whereas the second one is endowed with the discrete topology. It is not second countable and it has uncountably many connected components (the subsets of the form $\Bbb R\times\{a\}$).

Answer (score 1):

In such situation there's a Lie group for any (cardinal) number of components and for any dimension. Simply take any group with discrete topology. It is a Lie group of dimension $0$ and has as many components as its cardinality. In order to get higher dimension simply take product of the previous Lie group with your favourite Lie group of positive dimension (e.g. $\mathbb{R}^n$).